# I am new to Oracle and need to create a column that counts the number of time a particular list of codes appear based on id and type

Tags: oracle

I have the table below and would like to create a column that counts the number a times an id and type appears. I need to write a code that reflects the count column.

[image]

I have tried the following code

SELECT DISTINCT
type,
id,
code
FROM Table1
WHERE BEGIN_DATE BETWEEN '01-JAN-2021' AND '31-DEC-2022'
AND CODE IN ('11111','12545','13556','23566','14566')
group by type, id
having count(code)>1;

Comment: Please [edit] the question and include a [MRE] with: the `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT` statements for your sample data (as text we can copy/paste and execute, not images we cannot and showing all the input columns as your query mentions `begin_date`); an English (not code) explanation of the logic you are trying to implement (it is unclear why you are using `HAVING` in your code as that does not appear to match with your description); and the expected output (again, as text formatted using markdown and as an not image).

Answer (score 0):

You appear to want to use the `COUNT` analytic function:

```sql
SELECT type,
       id,
       code,
       COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY type, id) AS cnt
FROM   Table1
WHERE  begin_date >= DATE '2021-01-01'
AND    begin_date <  DATE '2023-01-01'
AND    code IN ('11111','12545','13556','23566','14566');
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table1 (type, id, code, begin_date) AS
SELECT 'AAA', 444444, 11111, DATE '2021-01-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'AAA', 444444, 12545, DATE '2021-01-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'AAA', 444444, 13556, DATE '2021-01-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'AAA', 444444, 23566, DATE '2021-01-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'CCC', 888888, 11111, DATE '2021-01-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'CCC', 888888, 12545, DATE '2021-01-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'CCC', 888888, 13556, DATE '2021-01-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'CCC', 888888, 23566, DATE '2021-01-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'CCC', 888888, 14566, DATE '2021-01-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'MM',  222222, 11111, DATE '2021-01-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'MM',  222222, 12545, DATE '2021-01-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'MM',  222222, 13556, DATE '2021-01-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'AAA', 333333, 21222, DATE '2021-01-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'MM',  777777, 51152, DATE '2021-01-01' FROM DUAL
```

Outputs:

| TYPE | ID | CODE | CNT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AAA | 444444 | 11111 | 4 |
| AAA | 444444 | 12545 | 4 |
| AAA | 444444 | 13556 | 4 |
| AAA | 444444 | 23566 | 4 |
| CCC | 888888 | 11111 | 5 |
| CCC | 888888 | 12545 | 5 |
| CCC | 888888 | 14566 | 5 |
| CCC | 888888 | 23566 | 5 |
| CCC | 888888 | 13556 | 5 |
| MM | 222222 | 11111 | 3 |
| MM | 222222 | 12545 | 3 |
| MM | 222222 | 13556 | 3 |

*Note: The last two rows are not in the output as they do not match your `IN` list.*

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/wpExKHDe)